my momma cat is fighting all of my cats all of a sudden
My cat Azzy had kittens a couple weeks ago and ever since then shes been on a tyrant. She was getting along great with my other cat Anya who they would literally stay together in the box with the kittens together. They would groom the kittens together, Anya would watch the kittens for Azzy so she can use the bathroom eat etc. but all of a sudden last night Azzy and Anya started fighting really bad and I cant get them to stop. I have another cat that azzy does not get along with but she spends time outside instead. Everytime Azzy sees either cat she goes in fighting mode. Somebody give me some pointers on how to get them to stop fighting they all used to get along very well.
